# Есть ли возможность поддержки русского языка для библиотеки pyfiglet для работы со шрифтами?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pyfiglet

def interpritate(par1,par2):
 
print(par1,par2)

par1 =(input('Введите текст для конвертации:'))

par2 = (int(input('Введите тип текста:')))

match par2:
    
case 1:
      print(pyfiglet.figlet_format(par1, font='banner3-D'))
    
case 2:
      print(pyfiglet.figlet_format(par1, font='isometric1'))
    
case 3:
      print(pyfiglet.figlet_format(par1, font='3-d'))
    
case 4:
      print(pyfiglet.figlet_format(par1, font='banner'))
```

Comment: Алан, отредактирован заголовок и код согласно правилам сайта. Обратите внимание на будущее.

Comment: Спасибо Сергей .На будущее учту